# Renderpartial() Don't Generate New Jquery Code For AjaxSubmitButton

Tags: php, yii

There is two actions in the controller:

**CProfile:**

```
public function actionCProfile()
{
$model=$this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
$model->scenario = 'updateProfile';
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['User'])){
    $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];

    if($model->validate())
        if($model->save()){
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                Yii::app()->end('saved');
            else{
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('status','saved');
            }
        }

    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        if(!$model->validate())
            Yii::app()->end('!validate');
}

if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    $this->renderPartial('_cprofile',array('model'=>$model));
else
    $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,'form'=>'_cprofile'));
}
```

And **CPass:**

```
public function  actionCPass()
{
$model = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
$model->scenario = 'CPass';
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['User'])){
    $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
    if($model->validate()){
        if($model->verifyPassword($model->currentPass)){
            $model->changePassword($model->newPass);
            Yii::app()->end('changed');
        }
    }
}

if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    $this->renderPartial('_cpass',array('model'=>$model));
else
    $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,'form'=>'_cpass'));
}
```

And three view files:

**update.php:**

```
<?php
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->registerCssFile('/x/css/myDetailview.css');
$cs->registerCssFile('/x/css/upanel/user-profile.css');
$url = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/js/upanel.js';
$cs->registerScriptFile($url,CClientScript::POS_HEAD);

?>

<div id='user-profile-menu'>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo CHtml::link('profile',Yii::app()->createUrl('/upanel/user/CProfile'),array('id'=>'profile-change-link')) ?></li>
        <li><?php echo CHtml::link('change email',Yii::app()->createUrl('/upanel/user/CPass'),array('id'=>'pass-change-link')) ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id='container'>
<?php $this->renderPartial($form,array('model'=>$model)); ?>
</div>
```

**_cprofile.php:**

```
<div class="form" >
        <?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
            'id'=>'change-profile-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'action' => 'index.php?r=upanel/user/cprofile',
            'method' => 'post',
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                'validateOnChange'=>true,
                'validateOnType'=>false,
            ),
        ));
        ?>

.
.
.
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                $url=Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/CProfile');
                echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('update',$url,
                    array(
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'data'=>"js:$('#change-profile-form').serialize()",
                        'success'=>'callback',
                        'beforeSend'=>'before',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'update-button',
                        'class'=>'submit-button',
                    )
                );
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php $this->endWidget() ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,'resolve following errors: ') ?>
```

**_cpass.php:**

```
<div class="form">
        <?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
            'id'=>'change-pass-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => 'true',
            'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/CPass'),
            'method' => 'POST',
            'clientOptions' => array(
                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                'validateOnChange' => true,
                'validateOnType' => false,
            )
        ));
        ?>

.
.
.
        <div class="row">
            <?php
          $url=Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/CPass');
                echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('update',$url,
                    array(
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'data'=>"js:$('#change-pass-form').serialize()",
                        'success'=>'callback',
                        'beforeSend'=>'before',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>'update-button',
                        'class'=>'submit-button',
                    )
                );
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php $this->endWidget() ?>

</div> <!-- End Password Form -->
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model) ?>
```

---

## **Edit #1: **

See, i have a `view` page named `update.php` that in this page there is two links:

```
<div id='user-profile-menu'>
<ul>
    <li><?php echo CHtml::link('profile',Yii::app()->createUrl('/upanel/user/CProfile'),array('id'=>'profile-change-link')) ?></li>
    <li><?php echo CHtml::link('Change Password',Yii::app()->createUrl('/upanel/user/CPass'),array('id'=>'pass-change-link')) ?></li>
</ul>
```

The following JQuery code runs exsist `actions` in `controller`, that result is a `renderpartial()` one of these view files: `_cpass.php` or `_profile.php`

```
$('document').ready(function(){

$('#profile-change-link').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#container').load(link);
    return false;
})

$('#pass-change-link').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#container').load(link);
    return false;
})

});
```

In the controller `CProfile` action defined as `default action`. with this action there is no any problem in which of POST and Ajax methods.

But main problem: after that `_cpass.php` view replaced with `_profile` and have send the exist `form` in the `_profile` to `CPass` action for processing encountered with problem.
The problem is this:

Output of following code as expected is `1`:

```
    public function  actionCPass()
{
    $model = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $model->scenario = 'CPass';
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (1==1)
        Yii::app()->end('1');
}
```

But output of following code is not that thing we expected. Returned value is a `renderpartial()` of `_profile` view. while there is no any related code about `_cprofile` view in `CPass` action code!

```
    public function  actionCPass()
{
    $model = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $model->scenario = 'CPass';
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User'])){
        $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
        if($model->validate()){
            if($model->verifyPassword($model->currentPass)){
                $model->changePassword($model->newPass);
                Yii::app()->end('changed');
            }
        }
    }

    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        $this->renderPartial('_cpass',array('model'=>$model));
    else
        $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,'form'=>'_cpass'));
}
```

Output of above code:

```
<div class="form" >

        <form id="change-profile-form" action="index.php?r=upanel/user/cprofile" method="post">
.
.
.                      
        <div class="row">

            <input id="update-button" class="submit-button" type="submit" name="yt0" value="update" />        </div>

        </form>

</div> <!-- End The Profile Form  -->

<div id="change-profile-form_es_" class="errorSummary" style="display:none">resole following errors:
<ul><li>dummy</li></ul></div>
```

Now understand what is the issue? The problem there is only with **Ajax** request and when disabled the **javascript** in the browser the `CPass` action acts truly.

Excuseme if firstly explained very bad.

Thanks friends

---

## **Edit #2: **

When debugging with Firebug i noticed that snippet of JQuery code didn't change.

When firstly in `default action` of `controller` this code:

```
$this->renderPartial('_cprofile',array('model'=>$model));
```

be run following JQuery code will create: (As you know following code is related to **CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton**)

```
$('body').on('click','#update-button',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','data':$('#change-profile-form').serialize(),'success':callback,'beforeSend':before,'url':'/x/index.php?r=upanel/user/CProfile','cache':false});return false;});
```

So when `_cpass` view renders with `renderpartial()` method in `CPass` action, the above JQuery code must be changed but will not change. I guess it must be the following code:

```
$('body').on('click','#update-button',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','data':$('#change-cpass-form').serialize(),'success':callback,'beforeSend':before,'url':'/x/index.php?r=upanel/user/CPass','cache':false});return false;});
```

#### So my problem is with JQuery code generated for CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you remove irrelevant code parts?

Comment: Please add some clarification, you have a lot of code, what did you expect to happen? what happened instead (this has been answered). Thanks

Comment: **Post edited:** description the issue added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

With applying **uniqueId** for **ajaxSubmitButton** and setting `CController::processOutput()` to **True** in **Controller Action** solved.

### Summary Code:

**actionCPass:**

```
public function  actionCPass()
{
$model = $this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
$model->scenario = 'CPass';
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['User'])){
    $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
    if($model->validate()){
        if($model->verifyPassword($model->currentPass)){
            $model->changePassword($model->newPass);
            Yii::app()->end('changed');
        }
    }
}

if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    $this->renderPartial('_cpass',array('model'=>$model),false,true);
else
    $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model,'form'=>'_cpass'));
}
```

**_cpass.php:**

```
            .
            .
            .
            <?php
            echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                'update',
                Yii::app()->createUrl('upanel/user/CPass'),
                array(
                    'type'=>'POST',
                    'data'=>"js:$('#change-pass-form').serialize()",
                    'success'=>'callback',
                    'beforeSend'=>'before',
                ),
                array(
                    'id'=>'update-button'.uniqid(),
                    'class'=>'submit-button',
                )
            );
            .
            .
            .
        ?>
```

Comment: [NLSClientScript extends the CClientScript class smart loading javascript files and optionally merging/minifying js+css files](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nlsclientscript)

Answer (score 2):

1. Rename one/both of your button ids. This means the event handlers will be attached to different buttons.
2. Use `renderPartial('view.path',array(parameter_array),false,true);` when returning a view via Ajax. The last parameter of [`CController::renderPartial()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) calls [`CController::processOutput()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#processOutput) which inserts the required client scripts at appropriate places.

Comment: **@topher:** I've done these already but didn't result. **#1 solution worked truly but Ajax functionality lost!**

Comment: **@topher:** With mixing **#1** and **2** solutions solved.
**beware:** using from this code: `renderPartial('view.path',array(parameter_array),false,true);` in **Controller** instead **view**.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your problem, you are wondering why the page does not have the surrounding `<div id='profile-container'>` and `</div>`.

I think this may have something to do with the render functions only being able to run once per view called (so it only renders the inside view), you can test this by removing the renderPartial from the update page and see if it prints the blank div.

One way you could get around this is to instead of doing the two renders, always call each page (even in the ajax requests) but pass an extra attribute if it was an ajax request. Then on each of the pages begin and end a custom widget that contains the surrounding template you want on those pages (or just write it in manually).

Example:
**controller**

```
public function actionCProfile()
{
    // ... same as your example
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
        $this->renderPartial('_cprofile',array('model'=>$model, 'wasAjax'=>false));
    } else {
        $this->renderPartial('_cprofile',array('model'=>$model, 'wasAjax'=>true));
    }
}
```

then in your view just check if wasAjax is true, if it is then print the surrounding div (or extra elements). If this is big or could change later on, put it in a custom widget.